# How to denote a function mapping of two parameters to an output?

Tags: functions, notation

I am wondering how to denote something like this:

I have a function mapping two sets to a set of vectors and am currently denoting it as so:

$p: [F, \Sigma] \to S $

I am wondering if this is correct, and if not, what is?

I am a computer science student and did a year of mathematics at degree level, but that was a long time ago and I have forgotten a lot of the basics.

If I am wrong I would appreciate a semi in depth answer as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function mapping two arguments from $A$ and $B$ respectively to $C$ is denoted

$$f:A\times B\to C,$$

where $\times$ here denotes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I had forgotten. It looks so familiar now I see it again. PS. How did you center on here? I tried a \begin and \end{center}, but it did not like that.

Comment: @Clintonio: Double dollar signs. `$$f:A\times B\to C.$$` becomes $$f:A\times B\to C.$$